# Error using HttpClient in canActivate class | [ERROR] NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, canactivate

I've some troubles when I want to use HttpClient in a CanActivate class.
I want to do some POST request in order to find my token in a Django API.
Examples are better than words :

**auth.guard.ts** :

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) { }

    async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

        const expectedRole: string[] = route.data['expectedRole'];

        if (localStorage.getItem('token') == null) {
            this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
            return false;
        }
        this.http.post<any>('api/verify-token/', {
            token: localStorage.getItem('jwt')
        }).subscribe((data) => {
            if (!expectedRole.includes(data.role)) {
                this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
              }
              return true;
        }, err => {
            this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
            return false;
        }
        )

        return false;
    }
}
```

**app.route.ts** :

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AddUserComponent } from './add-user/add-user.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth.guard';

export const routes: Routes = [
    // routes...
    { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { expectedRole: ['Administrateur'] } },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule], 
    providers: []
})

export class AppRouteModule { }
```

also, this is my `app.module.ts` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule, // Import the HttpClientModule here
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and when I try to access to my route, I have this error :

```bash
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_AuthGuardService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get 
    at R3Injector.get 
    at R3Injector.get 
    at injectInjectorOnly 
    at Module.ɵɵinject 
    at Object.AuthGuardService_Factory
    at eval 
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext 
    at R3Injector.hydrate 
    at R3Injector.get  {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [ '_AuthGuardService', '_HttpClient', '_HttpClient' ]
```

Can you explain me where I'm wrong please

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `HttpClientModule` into the `app.module.ts` or the root module you are using

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [HttpClientModule],
  providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hi thanks !

I already add it into my `app.module.ts` but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

When using services provided in `root` then you can use `inject()` to add the dependencies like shown below!

```
import { Injectable, NgModule, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    private router = inject(Router));
    private http= inject(HttpClient));
    constructor() { }

    async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

        const expectedRole: string[] = route.data['expectedRole'];

        if (localStorage.getItem('token') == null) {
            this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
            return false;
        }
        this.http.post<any>('api/verify-token/', {
            token: localStorage.getItem('jwt')
        }).subscribe((data) => {
            if (!expectedRole.includes(data.role)) {
                this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
              }
              return true;
        }, err => {
            this.router.navigate(['http://localhost:3000']);
            return false;
        }
        )

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I put your lines, I've got : 

```bash
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Environment Injector)[_AuthGuardService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
```

Comment: @Alos please provide a stackblitz with the issue replicated, for debugging!

Comment: I solved it by adding `provideHttpClient()`in `app.config.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have imported HttpClientModule in the module where your AuthGuardService is declared.

If the issue persists, try restarting the development server. Sometimes, the Angular development server may not pick up changes correctly. Stop the server (Ctrl + C in the terminal) and restart it using the command: `ng serve`.